# Add Items to cart without the user logged in react.js and redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I am working on a shopping cart in a single page application.

Currently the logged in user can add items to his cart and I am storing items into the user table in the mongoose using react, redux, Express.js and mongoose but now I want the non logged in users to add items to the cart.

Facing the issue in the logic in how can i manage this because if the user is not logged in then how can i store the cart items which the user has added? many non logged in users can add items to cart but how would i know which cart belongs to which user as they are not logged in (if i store cart in a database table).

for example the questions i am facing:

1. Where the cart items will be stored.
2. If i save them in the mongoose database then how will i know on which browser which user has added this item to the cart because the user is not logged in and it is single page application so i can not utilize session as i can do in php.
3. How will i sync the cart items to the user after he login because the user is on browser and i did not have user id when he has added the item to the cart.

Comment: I would recommend to use localStorage in the browser.

Comment: @Molda thanks for answering but can you please explain it more mean how it will work as i am new to react and redux hope you dont mind...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintain the state in `localStorage`. You could stringify the entire json and store it an item called `cart`

```
const cartObj = {
  item1: {},
  item2: {},
}

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartObj));

// getting back the object
const copyCartObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
```

**Note:** If you use `sessionStorage` it will get destroyed once you close the tab. So you requirement is as such you use it otherwise go with `localStorage`.

Hope this helps. Any doubts ping me in the comments.